# SQL Server Tables Relationship in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007, relational-database

I connected a sql server through ODBC and lined sql tables. I manually created my relationships in my database but, when I do that, my other tables are not editable. My drop downs I created won't allow me to select it or my text box doesn't let me type in it.

How am I supposed to create a relationship so I can use Access as a front-end to enter in data into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are linking to tables that exist already in SQL Server, then you don't need to worry about creating relationships in Access.

If you want to edit data in the SQL Server tables, make sure that you have a primary key on each table, and if possible a field with at "timestamp" data type.